# Failed to compile. webpack is not a function

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

My project was working fine but after installing react-redux and redux i can't start the project it shows me this error

Failed to compile.

webpack is not a function

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.1.0 start script.
```

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

[The screenshot of error in ternimal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSh9I.png)

Comment: Do you have Webpack installed globally or locally?

Comment: it would be helpful to show your code for start.js if possible

Comment: i have created a start.js file here in this Plnkr, please take a look.
http://plnkr.co/edit/EbQDizLIzOzJJ3rML0DU?p=preview

Comment: @James i have installed it locally but i tried to install globally it showed me this error

`npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for http://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ECONNABORTED: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/acorn failed, reason: connect ECONNABORTED 104.16.20.35:80
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from http://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code ECONNABORTED
npm ERR! errno ECONNABORTED
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs%2fwasm-edit failed, reason: connect ECONNABORTED 104.16.20.35:80`

Comment: @GulzarYousaf looks like you are trying to connect over an insecure connection (http), you'll need to check your npm settings. However, local is fine, can you post your package.json?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I ran into a problem with this same symptom after upgrading all of my node modules including react and redux, but in particular react-dev-utils to v8.0.0. The `createCompiler()` function has been changed to expect an object rather than multiple parameters (I guess this will provide greater flexibility in the future).

I changed my start.js from:

```
const compiler = createCompiler(webpack, config, appName, urls, useYarn);
```

to:

```
const compiler = createCompiler({ webpack, config, appName, urls, useYarn });
```

Comment: Worked like a charm - Thanks for sharing the solution!

Comment: Had the exact same issue.  I was wondering what caused it and even checked out a previous build wondering if I needed to revert any dependency updates for a last-known version.  

Your simple fix worked like a charm.  OP, I'd make this the accepted answer.

Comment: Did not work for me. `"react-dev-utils": "^9.0.1"`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Afraid not. All I can really say is that I'm now on v9.0.1 and this solution is still working fine. Do you still get the webpack is not a function error?

Comment: @Akhilesh it's because of one or both of the last boolean parameters, mine was like this: `const compiler = createCompiler({ webpack, config, appName, urls, false, false });` Either remove them, or make sure you pass them like `useYarn: false`... or use a variable with the same name like in this answer `useYarn` and `useTypeScript`.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I received ```TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined``` after making the changes suggested in this answer.

Comment: @CameronCobb This answer fixed that TypeError (for me): https://stackoverflow.com/a/62287792/107106

Answer (score -4):

Simple npm install command worked form me