# 'TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined'

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, redux, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm working on a project in React and ran into a problem that has me stumped.

Whenever I run `yarn start` I get this error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type
> string. Received type undefined

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Try deleting and re-installing node modules again.

Comment: Closing and opening the bash worked for me 

Comment: If you are arriving here after June 2020, you should check this answer instead of the accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62287792/147562

Comment: In my case I was using `const path = require( "path" )` and then using `path` to join a subdirectory like `path.join( myDirectoryName )`. However, `myDirectoryName` was sometimes `null` and that's what was causing this error to occur.

Comment: This happened for me after upgrading RedwoodJS via `yarn rw upgrade`. Reverting that commit and running `yarn install` again (to downgrade) fixed the problem for me. I'll figure out the Redwood upgrade later.

Comment: Still facing this issue on `react-scripts: 4.0.3` I had to downgrade to `react-scripts: 3.4.0` It's really disturbing. 

Answer (score 454, accepted):

To fix this issue simply upgrade **react-scripts** package (check latest version with `npm info react-scripts version`):

1. Replace in your *package.json* `"react-scripts": "^3.x.x"` with `"react-scripts": "^3.4.1"` (or the latest available version)
2. (optional for some) Delete your *node_modules* folder
3. Run `npm install` or `yarn install`

Some people reported that this issue was caused by running `npm audit fix` (avoid it!).

Comment: My issue was resolved when indeed upgrading from `3.3.0` to `3.4.0`. The weird thing is that is just stopped working in the middle of development, without any reason.

Comment: Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: I was also working when suddenly it started to happen.. why was this happening?

Comment: thanks. I did the same and it didn't work. My issue was npm cache, so had to delete node_modules, as proposed here.  Just leaving the comment,  as a record.

Comment: See the linked comment from this GitHub issue thread: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8499#issuecomment-589561657

Breaking change here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/commit/1cbc6f7db62f78747cb6ca41450099181139325e#diff-595228c9c4e2f6619c6bb1478ba4ef87R14

Comment: This 'just started' happening to me too, but it was really after running `npm audit fix`, in case that's useful to anyone.

Comment: I just changed the changed the react-script version to ^3.4.0 and ran yarn install and it resolved the problem. Didn't need to delete node_modules folder

Comment: Sadly it doesn't fix it for me! :(

Comment: Wow this actually fixed it. for awhile it would work with just SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true but tonight it gave me the path  argument of type string error and this solution fixed it.

Comment: I didn't have to remove `node_modules`, simply running `npm update` after changing the package version worked for me.

Comment: this started occuring after running "npm audit fix"

Comment: Here is a tip: never run "npm audit fix". It will likely ruin your project and make you want to punch a wall.

Comment: I kept on seeing a warning that I should run yarn upgrade. After doing so, I ran into this issue, and the answer fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: After running "npm audit fix" I faced the "TypeError" issue. Above solution worked for me.

Comment: Double-check that your version of react-scripts is set to ^3.4.1 in package.json.  This was my problem.  No amount of re-installing will work if this isn't set correctly.

Comment: In my Package didnt have ther version of react-scripts so, 
I had to run this command yarn add react-scripts@latest

Comment: How could you fix it if you don't want to upgrade react?

Comment: In my case the main issue was 'react-scripts' is locked in to a specific version. Prefix it with `^` and run `npm update`

Comment: I have this problem with v4.0.3

Comment: for me "rm yarn.lock" and "yarn install" fixed it. My go-to fix for yarn problems nowadays...:(

Answer (score 76):

If you have ejected, this is the proper way to fix this issue:

find this file `config/webpackDevServer.config.js` and then inside this file find the following line:

```
app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware());
```

You should change it to:

```
app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware('/'));
```

For me(and probably most of you) the service worker is served at the root of the project. In case it's different for you, you can pass your base path instead.

Answer (score 49):

I've also faced this problem and figure out it by upgrading the `react-scripts` package from `"react-scripts": "3.x.x"` to `"react-scripts": "^3.4.1"` (or the latest available version).

1. Delete `node_modules\` folder
2. Delete `package-lock.json` file
3. Rewrite the `package.json` file from **`"react-scripts": "3.x.x"`** to **`"react-scripts": "^3.4.1"`**
4. Install node packages again `npm i`
5. Now, start the project `npm start`

**And it works!!**

Comment: latest version is `3.4.1` since 21 March 2020

Comment: do not delete package-lock! unless you want all you package versions to be messed up upon the next `npm i`, then by all means, delete package-lock

Answer (score 20):

Running `npm i react-dev-utils@10.0.0` solved my issue.

Answer (score 11):

I just had this issue after installing and removing some npm packages and spent almost 5 hours to figure out what was going on.

What I did is basically copied my src/components in a different directory, then removed all the node modules and package-lock.json (if you are running your app in the Docker container, remove images and rebuild it just to be safe); then reset it to my last commit and then put back my src/components then ran `npm i`.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

We ejected from `react-scripts` and so could not simply upgrade the package.json entry to fix this.

Instead, we did this:

1. in a new directory, create a new project -> `$> npx create-react-app foo-project`
2. and then eject it -> `cd ./foo-project && npm run eject`
3. now copy the files from /foo-project/config into the config directory of our main app and fire up your dev server

hope this helps others in a similar bind.

Answer (score 9):

Simply update react-scripts to the latest version.

```
yarn add react-scripts@latest
```

OR IF USING NPM

```
npm install react-scripts@latest
```

Answer (score 5):

this has nothing to do with `react`, as the error specified, undefined is not accepted as the path argument. make sure you don't pass a variable to path.join that happens to be undefined or null.
for example:

```
const {path} = require('path'); 
let arg = undefined;
let mypath = path.join(__dirname, arg);

// The same error would occur.
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to you package.json
2. Change "react-scripts": "3.x.x" to "react-scripts": "^3.4.0" in the dependencies
3. Reinstall react-scripts: `npm I react-scripts`
4. Start your project: `npm start`

Answer (score 2):

If you ejected and are curious, [this change](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/7259) on the CRA repo is what is causing the error.

To fix it, you need to apply their changes; namely, the last set of files:

- packages/react-scripts/config/paths.js
- packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js
- packages/react-scripts/package.json
- packages/react-scripts/scripts/build.js
- packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js

Personally, I think you should manually apply the changes because, unless you have been keeping up-to-date with all the changes, you could introduce another bug to your webpack bundle (because of a dependency mismatch or something).

**OR**, you could do what Geo Angelopoulos suggested. It might take a while but at least your project would be in sync with the CRA repo (and get all their latest enhancements!).

Answer (score 1):

If you have an **ejected** `create-react-app`, I would suggest:

1. Create a new React app through `create-react-app`.
2. Eject it through `npm run eject` or `yarn eject`.
3. Install all the packages that are missing from the `package.json`.
4. Copy your **src** folder assuming all your code is situated in this folder.
5. Redo your changes on the **config** and **script** folders, if needed.

*Worked for me.*

Answer (score 1):

I tried various approach described above but none of them worked since I have **ejected** my css. Finally applying following steps helped:

1. Upgrade`react-scripts` from `"react-scripts": "3.x.x"` to `"react-scripts": "^3.4.0"`
2. Downgrading `react-dev-utils` form `"react-dev-utils": "^10.x.x"` to `"react-dev-utils": "10.0.0"`
3. Delete `node-modules` folder and `package-lock.json`/`yarn.lock`
4. Reinstall packages `npm install`/`yarn install`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to upgrade `react-scripts`, so I used the 3rd party [reinstall npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-reinstall) to reinstall it, and it worked.

```
npm i -g npm-reinstall
reinstall react-scripts
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ejected CRA, there are a few changes to the webpack-dev-server config that if left unchanged will throw this error. Comparing a freshly ejected CRA 4.x config to my CRA 3.x config showed a number of changes to functions that didn't previously accept arguments that now do.

In my case, one of the breaking changes was the addition of a path to their `noopServiceWorkerMiddleware` function. Adding in the missing path `noopServiceWorkerMiddleware(paths.publicUrl)` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simply upgrading `react-scripts` version solved my issue.
`react-scripts` package from `"react-scripts": "3.x.x"` to `"react-scripts": "^3.4.1"` (or the latest available version).
Avoid deleting `package-lock.json` straightaway. First try this, if it doesn't work then proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

Switching from powershell to bash fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

A very similar (misleading) error also occurs when running the `react-native bundle` command without arguments.

Provide both `--entry-file` and `--bundle-output` for a successful run:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --bundle-output ./index.jsbundle
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have added a **package** in package.json and you removed it. remember to delete any configuration added in **/config/plugin.js** or anywhere else related to that package.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps. I also encountered the same problem.

1. remove the whole node_modules folder.
2. remove the package-lock.json file.
3. run command `npm install npm-install` as shown in the image:

   [image: showing the command to install npm]
4. Here we go.. npm start...wao

Answer (score 0):

Just need to remove and re-install `react-scripts`

To Remove
`yarn remove react-scripts`
To Add
`yarn add react-scripts`

and then `rm -rf node_modules/ yarn.lock && yarn`

- Remember don't update the `react-scripts` version maually

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running it in my pipeline.

For me, the issue was that I was using `node` version `v10.0.0` in my docker container.

Updating it to `v14.7.0` solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Setting the HOME environment variable to an appropriate value fix this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by setting a newer version of node as default in nvm i.e.:

```
nvm alias default 12.XX.X
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue for a gatsby blog. The dependencies couldn't be upgraded and could only run on npm version 10.22.1.

What works for me is the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf .cache
rm -rf public
gatsby build
gatsby serve
```

Basically the completely rebuild everything, and this error is gone. Very annoying but at least it builds.

What's ever more weird is that, if I tweaked the image of the blog post, e.g., resizing it a bit, it builds. I have absolutely no idea why. But that least that's a clue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I previously changed the folder path, and then only I got that error when using `npm start`.

So, I changed the folder path `C:\Users\User\Documents\### Coding\todo-app` into `C:\Users\User\Documents\Coding\todo-app` and then it worked.

I think the problem was using those special characters in the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by deleting Firebase Hosting cache folder:

.firebase

I am not using react-scripts although I was before I converted to vite. Also, my issue occurred when deploying to a new firebase project.