# Reactjs ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE

Tags: javascript, reactjs

there!
I bought some template from themeforest and everything works fine with previews version, but with the new one I'm having error like

```
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type
> string. Received type undefined
>         at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
>         at Object.join (path.js:427:7)
>         at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\react-dev-utils\noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
>         at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>         at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>         at C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>         at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>         at next (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>         at launchEditorMiddleware (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\react-dev-utils\errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
>         at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>         at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>         at C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>         at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>         at next (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>         at handleWebpackInternalMiddleware (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\react-dev-utils\evalSourceMapMiddleware.js:42:7)
>         at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\gComet-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

I believe that template is not supposed to have this error, but still I have it. What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to provide the code. From the surface, it is complaining about `validators.js` at the function `validateString` where the `path` argument is undefined.

Comment: Please check this reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/60242323/5146848

Answer (score 7):

You can check this link https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20503

To fix this issue simply upgrade to `"react-scripts": "^3.4.0"`

1. Overwrite the existing `"react-scripts": "^3.x.x"` with`"react-scripts": "^3.4.0"` in your package.json
2. Delete your node modules
3. Finally run `npm install` or `yarn install` into your command prompt.

i hope it will fix it.