# RunError on a React Project

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux

When I run the project on react I got the following error. I tried to reinstall node_module but it didn't help. Maybe someone have faced the same problem?

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:118:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1039:7)
    at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (/home/asel/social-network/node_modules/react-dev-utils/noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/asel/social-network/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/asel/social-network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/asel/social-network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/asel/social-network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/asel/social-network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at launchEditorMiddleware (/home/asel/social-network/node_modules/react-dev-utils/errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/asel/social-network/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/asel/social-network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/asel/social-network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/asel/social-network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/asel/social-network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at handleWebpackInternalMiddleware (/home/asel/social-network/node_modules/react-dev-utils/evalSourceMapMiddleware.js:42:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/asel/social-network/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: node - v13.9.0, npm - 6.13.7, OS linux ubuntu 18.04, react - ^16.12.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError \[ERR\_INVALID\_ARG\_TYPE\]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined raised when starting react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234640/typeerror-err-invalid-arg-type-the-path-argument-must-be-of-type-string-re)

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade `react-scripts` package from v3.3.0 to v3.4.0

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8490