# TypeScriptError: Type 'Data' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-typescript

I am using React-typescript for my app. for state management I am using [Redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/). I am fetching one [open api](https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/5) and store it my redux store. I created dispatch function. From the component when I click the dispatch function then it will display random dog image. But the problem is after mapping the when I am using this img src. I am getting typescript error: `Type 'Data' is not assignable to type 'string'.` I don't know what I am doing wrong. i uploaded my code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-si0dd?file=/src/App.tsx), although it works in codesandbox but does not work in my app.

Ps. I did not upload my store setup code because it works find ☺️.

**This is my reducer**

```js
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/indent */
    import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
    import { AppThunk } from "store/store";
    
    interface IMeta {
      loading: boolean;
      error: boolean;
      message: string;
    }
    
    interface Data {
      src: string;  
    }
    
    interface IDogs {
      meta: IMeta;
      dogs: Data[];
    }
    
    const initialState: IDogs = {
      "meta": {
        "loading": false,
        "error": false,
        "message": ``
      },
      "dogs": []
    };
    
    const dogSlice = createSlice({
      "name": `random-dogs`,
      initialState,
      "reducers": {
        loadState(state) {
          state.meta = {
            "loading": true,
            "error": false,
            "message": ``
          };
          state.dogs = [];
        },
        fetchData(state, action: PayloadAction<Data[]>) {
          state.meta.loading = false;
          state.dogs = action.payload;
          console.log(`dogs`, action.payload);
        },
        loadFailed(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
          state.meta = {
            "loading": false,
            "error": true,
            "message": action.payload
          };
          state.dogs = [];
        }
      }
    
    });
    
    export const { loadState, fetchData, loadFailed } = dogSlice.actions;
    export default dogSlice.reducer;
    
    export const fetchDogs = (): AppThunk => async (dispatch) => {
      const url = `https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/5`;
    
      try {
        dispatch(loadState);
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.message);
        const singleData = data.message.map((i) => i);
        dispatch(fetchData(singleData));
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch(loadFailed(`dogs are unavailable`));
        console.log({ error });
      }
    };
```

**This is the component I am using the redux store**

```js
    import React, { memo } from 'react';
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
    import { fetchDogs } from 'store/dogs';
    import { RootState } from 'store/combineReducer';
    
    export default memo(() => {
      const state = useSelector((rootState: RootState) => ({
        "dogs": rootState.fetchDogs.dogs,
        "meta": rootState.fetchDogs.meta
      }));
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      console.log(`Dog component`, state.dogs[0]);
    
      return (
        <div>
          {state.meta.loading ? <p>loading....</p> :
            state.dogs.map((i, index) =>
              <div key={index}>
                <ul>
                  <li>{i}</li> // I can see the strings
                </ul>
                <img style={{ "width": 50, "height": 50 }} src={i} /> //getting error in here
              </div>)}
          <br></br>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch(fetchDogs())}> display random dogs</button>
        </div>
      );
    });
```

Comment: the `i` is actually an integer. You can try to forceit like `<img ... src={`${i}`} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation is as follows:

- Interface IDog is has a property "dogs" of type Data[].
- Data has a property "src" of type String.
- Src attribute of an img needs to be a string.

You are now passing IDogs.dogs. You need to go deeper to IDogs.dogs.src to get the source string you want.

So line 25 of App.tsx should look like this and all seems to work fine:

`<img style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }} src={i.src} alt="dog" />`

PS: The codesandbox example still works as it apparently does some kind of assumption that you want the src property, but as you see you still get the error.

---

**EDIT**: After some fiddling the answer is as below. It is however connected to what was written above.

I downloaded you project and tried to run in npm on my PC. I did 2 things to make it work:

1. I updated line 25 to use the cast: `src={String(i)}`
2. I updated react-scripts. See this thread for reference: [TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined raised when starting react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234640/typeerror-err-invalid-arg-type-the-path-argument-must-be-of-type-string-re)

Comment: when I tried with `<li>{i.src}</li>` then it did not display the list as well.

Comment: Indeed, I think I that's not necessairly a problem. Casting seems to fix the issue, have you tried in your project?

`src={String(i)}`

Comment: I downloaded you project and tried to run in npm on my PC. I did 2 things to make it work. See the updated answer.