# install project reactjs failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to initialize a ReactJS project by installing a ReactJS environment with CRA
A failed type refusal returned to me

**I installed my nodeJS environment as follows:**

node v14.15.4
npm v6.14.10

the paths of these utility is:

node: / usr / local / bin / node
npm: / usr / local / bin / npm

then I launched the official command to install a reactJS environment with CRA:

npx create-react-app my-app

**THE SERVER RESPONSE IS:**

**AT THE START OF EXECUTION:**

```
Creating a new React app in / Users / macbookpro / test.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template ...

➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0032: │ fsevents @ npm: 2.3.1: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0032: │ fsevents @ npm: 2.3.1: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
```

**AT THE END EXECUTION:**

```
➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 2m 52s

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd / Users / macbookpro / test has failed.

Deleting generated file ... package.json
Deleting generated file ... yarn.lock
Done.
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the yarn cache with:

```
yarn cache clean
```

and then run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Type Error: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined

Comment: Take a look to this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234640/typeerror-err-invalid-arg-type-the-path-argument-must-be-of-type-string-re

Answer (score 0):

Try to install yarn in your system using this:

```
npm install -g yarn
```

And then:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Best regards!