# npm doesn't run correctly for react js

Tags: json, reactjs, npm

when I want to run my project on react this error appears...how to solve it?

````
W:\Burgerapp>npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path W:\Burgerapp\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'W:\Burgerapp\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Polymer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-11T13_03_57_137Z-debug.log ```
````

Comment: show the content of w:\Burgerapp

Comment: it seems you are not in the correct folder to execute this command.

Comment: @JeffRSon which file? is json enough? bcuz problem comes from it

Comment: `dir` should probably be enough ;-) Just read the error message...

Comment: If there is indeed a file `package.json` then I'd assume your user "Polymer" is not allowed to open the file. This may be related to the type of drive W: - what is it? You might try to copy BurgerApp to the system hard drive below c:\Users\Polymer and try again from this folder.

Comment: Unfortunately can not add picture...but a question:
I have copied this json file from another directory...am I allowed to do that?
if not how can I solve it by NPM? @JeffRSon

Comment: the error message is not related to the content of package.json, but says it cannot find (or open) it

Comment: I moved folder to windows' drive, didn't work but error changed to:
```
webpack is not a function
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Polymer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-11T13_57_25_637Z-debug.log```
@JeffRSon

Comment: Then you need to show scripts/start.js. Look here if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55140033/failed-to-compile-webpack-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are writing "npm start" in the wrong place because there is no  "package.json" file in the directory.

Comment: u know I coped and pasted json file from another folder...is not this the case?